# Setting AutoHideSplashScreen has no effect in Cordova 3.0.0 for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

Setting *AutoHideSplashScreen* to false has no effect in Cordova 3.0.0 for iOS.
I'd like to control the splash screen by my own. Since the app needs some seconds to render the view it needs to be shown a bit longer.
The 'navigator.splashscreen' is installed within the project.
Is there any workaround i can apply to this?

**Note**
I mentioned that setting *FadeSplashScreen* and *FadeSplashScreenDuration* do also have no effect.

What am i doing wrong? Or is it a bug?

Comment: I can confirm this, see my post on the list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/MX5VRmL3HwY

Will let you know _if_ I can find a workaround, although I dont have any clue right now.

Comment: Here's the related JIRA issue, as well: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4374 - might be worth watching : )

Comment: thanks, i am also watching this issue now. maybe someone already fixed this (i hope) so i dont close this question yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution was posted on this Cordova JIRA Issue CB-4374:

Try adding this in your config.xml for the Splashscreen plugin:

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

Comment: please check this question ""http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777044/cordovaphonegap-setting-splash-screen-is-not-working-fine-in-ios""

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the JIRA thread is to use the updated code at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/ios/CDVSplashScreen.m and to add an onload parameter in config.xml:

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
<preference name="orientation"      value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />
<preference name="webviewbounce"    value="false" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```