# phonegap ios white screen after splash - how to avoid

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using phonegap 2.9.0 (iOS). I followed suggestions from this forum and set 
    ... preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" ...
in config.xml and also added

```
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
```

in the deviceReady() function.

Still, I am seeing the white screen between splash and the remote web page load. The white screen duration varies - probably depending on network latency ??

How to avoid this intermediate white screen ?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Any chance this helps and/or is a duplicate? 

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821526/setting-autohidesplashscreen-has-no-effect-in-cordova-3-0-0-for-ios

Answer (score 3):

For ios@6.1.0 add this to config.hml

```
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **navigator.splashscreen.hide()** in **onDeviceReady(){}**
In your **config.xml** first you specify not to hide the splashscreen automatically (you have already added this)

```
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
```

Then when **onDeviceReady()** launches add a few seconds delay to **navigator.splashscreen.hide()**
 
So it will stay loaded for a few more seconds (2 seconds in this example) before it hides. This way it will overlap the white screen which would appear between the normal splash.hide() / onDeviceReady() and actually loading your main page of your app.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 2000);
}
```

So After WebView loads and before your code launces the splashscreen will be shown.

Comment: After applying this to a PhoneGap Build project the white page of the iOS version was gone, but now I'm getting a white page after the splash screen in the Android version. Is there a way to make it work for both?