# cordova[phonegap] Setting splash screen is not working fine in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have added **splash screen** for my phonegap app.

I am building phonegap app online at **http://build.phonegap.com**.

Splash Screen is working **fine for android**.But on **ios splash screen hides** before the defined time.

***Config.xml*** For Splash Screen

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        xmlns:android   = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id          = "com.clerisy.arcade"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</name>

    <description>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </description>

    <author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </author>

    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" /> 
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" /> 
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" /> 
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" /> 
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" /> 
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" /> 
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" /> 
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" /> 
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" /> 
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" /> 
    <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xff38c0f4"/>
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />   
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" /> 

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <!-- Core plugins -->

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.12" />
    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.3.8" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" version="1.1.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />

    <!-- Set Icon and splash screen -->

    <icon src="icon.png" platform="android" width="57" height="57" density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="screen.png"/>  
    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

to hide splashscreen i am using

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   // Hide splash Screen
   setTimeout(function() {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }, 2000);
```

The Problem is :-

it is working fine on android but on iphone it changes the resolution of splashscreen after few seconds.

Comment: did you manage to this?

Answer (score 2):

Install the splash screen plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

For iOS you have to hide splash screen inside timeout function in document ready, you can define the duration after which the splashscreen should hide.

```
setTimeout(function() {
                navigator.splashscreen.hide();
            }, 8000);
```

set autohide splash to false in config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Refer the plugin documentation for more detail https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: hi shinyJoes, i have updated my question.Please check it

Answer (score 0):

If you have apple device build uisng Xcode and add sleep in main thread of app (in app delegate) and you are done with it